# Return data to component that dispatches event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, polymer, dom-events, polymer-2.x

I have a deeply nested web component that dispatches an event with data:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('do-something', {
  bubbles: true,
  composed: true,
  detail: {
    itemId: itemId
  }
}));
```

I would like to conditionally handle the `event.detail` in a parent element and then return data back to the component that dispatched the event.

Currently I am selecting child nodes from parent nodes declaratively by `id` and passing the data back down through several functions.

```
passDataToFirstChild() {
  this.$.firstChildNode.property = this.dataComputedByParent.
}
```

...

```
passDataToSecondChild() {
  this.$.secondChildNode.property = this.dataPassedFromFirstChild.
}
```

*Is there a way to shortcut this process?*

I see that the event object has a `path` property, but I am not seeing an obvious way to integrate that array into a solution that would hook the child and parent node together.

**So, is there a way to directly connect a deeply nested child node with a parent node to pass data back and forth via events?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event detail you can send the reference of the node that dispatched the event.

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('do-something', {
  bubbles: true,
  composed: true,
  detail: {
    itemId: 'item id', 
    dispatcher: this
  }
}));
```

Listener in some parent

```
this.addEventListener('do-something', (e) => {
    e.detail.dispatcher.property = this.dataComputedByParent;
})
```

Comment: So it looks like this method attaches an object as a property to the event, but I am not understanding how the data gets passed back down the DOM tree.

Comment: Is the event object stored in memory space of the node that dispatched it?